# Function key commands changing by themselves?? very weird problem

Tags: 14.04, malware

I am afraid that my computer has been compromised. In exactly 10 different instances, I have been browsing the web in Kubuntu 14.04 and have noticed commands from the function keys that I did not execute.

The first time, the brightness control ( FN + up arrow ) popped up on the screen without my asking it.
then the volume command ( FN + right Arrow ) came up.
the brightness thing happened more than once. i could literally see the brightness indicator pop up on screen and start moving around; going from zero to 55%, then back down to zero several times.
and the strangest part is; IT ISN'T ALWAYS ONLINE!

As little as I know about Linux; I was under the impression that it was nearly impossible to hack. If someone has hijacked or hacked my laptop, I can see them screwing around with my system settings while the computer has an internet connection.
But this has happened when the computer was COMPLETELY offline, and no internet whatsoever!

has someone hijacked me?
is this a virus?
how can a key on a keyboard press itself? and how the hell can a hijacker access my computer if it's NOT on the internet

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this happen on my machine too, but my machine has touch/heat sensitive keys as well as the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys so when a fleck of cigarette ash falls on them (or just a spec of dust) they activate...

In your case (if you don't have heat sensitive keys), a hair or fleck of dust may be under your key, or your keyboard may be breaking down. (**Tip:** Vacuum your keyboard with your vacuum cleaner on the lowest setting)

If you are really worried, you can have the following command running on your system at all times:

`xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'`

(place the new window on a workspace you don't use often and test it out now so you can recognize the offending keys. When it happens, verify that the keys are being pressed and you will be able to sleep more tightly!)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not an intruder, especially if offline.

Probably bugs, funny hardware, or even dirty keys shorting themselves "on", vibration, bad ground...

To see if it still happens I'd try a (different?) live cd/usb, Kubuntu, regular Ubunut, Xubuntu, even a derived-from distro like Linux Mint, or the "source" distro Debian?

Comment: Haven't seen you in chat lately...  ;-) (I used to be known as "Fabby" ;-)

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW stackexchange can be a "time-burglar" so I try to pace myself, avoid unless I'm looking to/for help or to upvote ;-) Nice upside down backwards letters, I didn't even know they existed, but apparently are in XFCE Mint, paste to gedit just fine too. And wow, 29k rep, impressive!

Comment: These upside-down characters actually don't exist: it's just a combination of existing UNICODE characters that look like upside-down ones.  E.G. it starts with a D, then an N, dash, some runic character, ... ending in a W.  **:D**. But I'll be going back to Fabby on 6 March as most people hate it.